# Timestamp show wrong data

Tags: java, android, date, timestamp

Why **Timestamp((long)-62135596800000L) return 0001-01-03 00:00:00**, but must return **0001-01-01 00:00:00**? This service show correct Timestamp [here](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/)

[image]

Comment: Maybe the answer on that website is wrong?

Comment: In java it is -62135773200000L. Maybe the siete's calculation errs on leap year calculation; Gregorian/Julian calendar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-62135596800000` is 0001-01-03 00:00:00.0 Because [by default java uses Julian calendar for dates before October 15, 1582](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

The website you are using, uses javascript which uses extrapolated, or proleptic, Gregorian calendar for all dates. From [javascript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.3)

> ECMAScript uses an extrapolated Gregorian system to map a day number to a year number and to determine the month and date within that year.

Indeed, in javascript:

```
new Date(-62135596800000).toUTCString()
//"Mon, 01 Jan 1 00:00:00 GMT"
```

You can use something like this in java to gain the same results:

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
date.clear();
//Use Gregorian calendar for all values
date.setGregorianChange(new Date(Long.MIN_VALUE));

date.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
date.setTime(new Date(-62135596800000L));

System.out.println(
        date.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + "-" +
        (date.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + 
        date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) + " " +
        date.get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" +
        date.get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE) + ":" + 
        date.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND) + "." +
        date.get(GregorianCalendar.MILLISECOND)
);
//Prints 1-1-1 0:0:0.0
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to carry out the Gregorian change from `Calendar` to `Date` objects, so I am doing the formatting directly from the calendar object. If I just did
`formatter.format(date.getTime())` it would lose the Gregorian change setting and show 3rd day again.

The Julian date is 2 days ahead because according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar#Difference_between_Julian_and_proleptic_Gregorian_calendar_dates),
Julian is ahead of proleptic Gregorian by 2 days from 1 BC to 100 AD.

---

Btw, I recommend using [`JodaTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_instant.html), it correctly (my opinion, [though if you need something more convincing](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html)) defaults to pure Gregorian:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(-62135596800000L, DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(dt.toString());
//0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Extremely well put ... incredible!