# Parsing a JSON date that looks like this: /Date(-62135596800000)/

Tags: java, json, gson

I've come across a funky looking JSON date in some data I'm trying to parse in Java: `/Date(-62135596800000)/`. I have no issues parsing dates like these without the minus sign, but I'm not sure how to parse it with the minus. FYI I believe the date should represent sometime today (somewhere between 4-4:30 PM on 06/02/13 at GMT+10).

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Joseph.

Comment: Java time in millisecond are calculated assuming January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT (Gregorian) as 0 milliseconds. so I guess it should not be any problem in parsing this date.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668603/timestamp-show-wrong-data

Answer (score 1):

This is empty date returned from a WCF or MVC webservice . 
It is equivalent to null date .